# Cannot dismiss keyboard from UIPopover in monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, textfield, uipopover

I am having trouble to dismiss keyboard from UIPopover. I have text field in popover form when I run  this `ResignFirstResponder()` function nothing happening. Not sure why any idea. it is happening only when I run it from popover.

Is it because of it overlay and object. Need help?

Here some example of my code:
Here I am calling popover;

```
            if (this.CustomerID != 0) {
                var content = new BillingAddressViewController (this, this.CustomerBillingAddress);
                content.CustomerID = this.CustomerID;
                content.rootcontroller = this;
                DetailViewPopover = new UIPopoverController (content);
                DetailViewPopover.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF (300, 200);
                DetailViewPopover.PresentFromRect (this.customerBillingAddressCell.Frame, View, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
            } else {
                var x = new UIAlertView ("Notifcation Message", "Please choose customer to proceed with Billing Address", null, "OK");
                x.Show ();
            }

        };
```

Inside of popover content class I am calling

```
this.billingTextView.ResignFirstResponder();
```

on button trigger;

Answer (score 0):

in your `DissmisskeyBoard` method use the following code.

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

hope it will help you out.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
return YES;
}
```

Comment: is it duplicating anything. I have called this function both in rootview and in popover view

Comment: did you used **UITextfieldDelegate** in .h file and **textfield.delegate=self** in .m file ?

Comment: try to edit your question and post some codes then its easy to find the issue.

Comment: I cannot understand why it I am not having this kind of issue when I call it from root controller.

Comment: Hi, I found problem. it was because of segue. once I go from one view to another and come back again to the previous page. it stop to function not sure why but this is problem